# Prove that a finite abelian group A,with a subgroup B , C=A/B s.t gcd(o(B),(C))=1 can be written as direct sum of B and C' isomorphic to C

Tags: abstract-algebra

I can't think of a way to find such a C' (I think that one has to use the fact the fact that since A is a finite abelian group and hence it can be decomposed but can't proceed with it.)

Comment: What do you mean "find such a $C'$"? Isn't it already given to you that $C'$ is isomorphic to $C=A/B$?

Comment: No , I think you have to construct such a C' using the fact that A is a finite abelian group

Comment: If you can use the [fundamental theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_group#Classification) of finite abelian groups, I think this is straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

I use products instead of sums. The result is true for all nilpotent (not only Abelian) finite groups.

Since $A$ is nilpotent, it is a direct product of its Sylow subgroups $S_{p_1}\times...\times S_{p_m}$. Since the order and index of $B$ are coprime, $B$ is the product of some of the $S_{p_i}$ and $A/B$ is isomorphic to the product of the other Sylow subgroups of $A$. Hence $A$ is isomorphic to $B\times A/B$.